Data-Fetching with Nuxt causes CORS error only on route change
I am working on a Nuxt page, where I have multiple pages, fetching data from a CMS in each page file. On loading the page initally, everything works fine. However, when I navigate to a different page, the data fetching returns a CORS/preflight error.
My CMS does have set CORS to allow all origin, which is why I am thinking this might have something to do with the way my app is set up.
E.g. there is index.js with the following code:
<script setup>
const { getPageData } = getData();
const page = await getPageData('/');
</script>

My composable looks like this:
  const getPageData = (slug) => {
    const { data, error } = useAsyncData(`pageData-${slug}`, () =>
      $fetch(`${backendUrl}${slug}`, {
        headers: authHeader.headers,
        responseType: 'json',
      })
    );

    if (error.value) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.value);
      return null;
    }

    return data.value;
  };

I don't quite understand how it is possible that the CORS error only happens when navigating but not on initial page load – grateful for any hints!

You do not have any CORS issues initially because the first render of the page happens on the server side of Nuxt (if using SSR or SSG), the rest of the calls are called via client-side navigation, hence requiring CORS to be present. For those, the settings are probably slightly off, check your CMS again for any potential typos.
